# Hover line animation: inset on bottom border only instead of outset

Tags: css, border

This causes a line to appear below the text in a "swipe down motion" on hover. However, I want it to appear in a "swipe up action". Any clever solutions to this?

CSS:

```
.nav a {
color:#f90;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:700;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align:middle;
font-family:"oswald",sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
transition:color .2s, border-bottom 0.5s;
padding-bottom: 8px;
border-bottom:  none;
}

.nav a:hover {
color:#69D2E7;
border-bottom:  solid 14px #69D2E7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it

```
.nav a {
color:#f90;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:700;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align:middle;
font-family:"oswald",sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
transition:color .2s, padding-bottom 0.5s;
>>>>>>>>>>>padding-bottom: 18px;
border-bottom: solid 8px #69D2E7;
}

.nav a:hover {
color:#69D2E7;
>>>>>padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```